# Laptop is bootting directly into Windows 8

Tags: hp

I tried to install Ubuntu 14.04 LTS 64 bit  along side Windows 8.1 on my  HP 15-n203tx laptop.I created a bootable USB.

When I tried using legacy boot it didn't detect my Windows. So I tried something else option.In that I allotted 2GB for swap area and 10 GB for '/' .

Ubuntu showed installation successful and asked to continue testing/restart.But after restart, it took me back to Windows.I am not  able to boot Ubuntu.Is there any  solution?

Comment: Has Ubuntu turned up when you tried using legacy boot using boot time security disabled

Comment: when i restarted my pc it is booted into windows as if nothing is installed

Answer (score 0):

There is a feature in Windows 8 that's called Secure Boot, this feature prevents any other operating systems booting on that system. This can be pretty annoying. To disable Secure Boot, you have to look within the settings of Windows 8. You can search Secure Boot online for more information.